# Apache not killing child processes and hanging

Tags: apache-2.2

The server hits the MaxClients setting and then just hangs until manually restarted. I have a 512MB ram VPS and i've set the MaxClients setting to 10.
The child processes that apache spawns are not killed eventhough no connection to the server appears in netstat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use server status to see what the processes are doing:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_status.html

Comment: i managed to get mod status to work. And i see many requests to a specific file eventhough nobody is connected to the server. I stopped that site and now everything is back to normal. Thanks for the info. Any ideeas on how to prevent this in the future are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Even If you have no connection, apache will start some child to be able to quick answer to request (creating child process have a cost). You can parameter this with MinSpareServers, MaxSpareServers, and StartServers.

With 512MB, you can specify more than 10 MaxChild.